# Hidden field value is lost/reset on UpdatePanel update

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am using Javascript in ASP.NET website. I am also using the updatepanel in the code.
I am using hidden field which is present in updatepanel.

I want to use document.getelementbyID(hiddenfield);

but every time I update the updatepanel I do get the same value how can I get the updated value.
Thank You.

Comment: Possibly post some code or get a jsFiddle?

Comment: Have you verified, that the hidden field gets updated on the server side?

Comment: My response is to the last sentence in this post - but I'm not entirely sure the words written mean what I think they mean. Post code and try to expand on the problem more.

Answer (score 0):

My first "hunch" is that the server is not using the new value on a postback. *On each postback the **entire contents** of the updated UpdatePanels are replaced* - this includes the aforementioned hidden field.

Inspect the network requests in Firebug (or equivalent) and/or attach a debugger to the ASP.NET process. The first step is to determine exactly where/when the value is not as expected/desired.

Various frameworks (e.g. DevExpress, perhaps Telerik) provide custom hidden field controls that are smart enough to persist their data across postbacks. Such a control is relatively trivial to create or emulate.

One quick hack to persist the hidden field across *async* postbacks is to move it *outside* of any UpdatePanel .. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `ClientID property` because your control contain runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        var hiddenField = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
        alert(hiddenField.value);
    }
}
```

With so little code from your part, and no error it is hard to tell what really is going on, there could be many things wrong with it. You have to make sure you are using `document.getElementById` after the page's loaded, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post your code..and if you have placed your hiddenfield inside updatepanel then on every post back its value get re initialized. try placing it outside the update panel...

Hopefully this may fix your error if and all it is related to it..